# my pc always alert in reboot time set Date & Time in Windows 7.?

Tags: windows-7

The date and time don't show up alert set date/time in my Windows 7 in reboot time.i have Changing date and time everyday.

Comment: replace the CMOS battery

Comment: please explain brif

Comment: looks like a silver coin, keeps the lowest level of the computer's memory alive when powered off; including date & time - http://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/images/CMOS-Battery-3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable cause of the machine losing date & time every day is that the CMOS battery is flat.

The CMOS is a little bit of RAM that stores all the BIOS information so that each time the computer restarts or powers on, the computer can remember this information.
If the battery is flat, this information is lost when you power down, & each time you turn on your computer, the BIOS settings will reset and you will need to setup your BIOS again. Your computer will function but everything in your BIOS, such as the boot order, time and date, etc will reset.

The batteries are cheap & simple to replace. Take the old one with you when buying a new one, as a lot look very similar. Getting the same type is important.

Removal is as simple as pressing back the small black tab at one edge.
The new one can be just gently pressed into place, starting from the edge away from the tab.

[image]